# How to save multiple String element from List<String> into a db using JPA?

Tags: java, jsp, jpa, persistence

I tried so far the below code:

```
Session session = null;
Query query1 = null;
Query query2 = null;

String[] parts = userId.split("=");
userId = parts[1];
parts = userId.split(" ");
userId = parts[0];
int intIdUser = Integer.parseInt(userId);

try {
    session = getSession();

    UserCountry userCountry = new UserCountry();
    UserLanguage userLanguage = new UserLanguage();

    for (String s : user_country) {
        userCountry.setUserId(intIdUser);
        userCountry.setCountryId(Integer.parseInt(s));

        session.getTransaction().begin();
        session.persist(userCountry);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    for (String s : user_language) {
        userLanguage.setUserId(intIdUser);
        userLanguage.setLanguageId(Integer.parseInt(s));

        session.getTransaction().begin();
        session.persist(userLanguage);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}

catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error("Exception while fetching for countryId: "+userId, e);
    throw new PlRuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
finally {
    if(session !=null)
        session.close();
}
```

But the for (String s : user_country) and for (String s : user_language) loops are saving just first element on the list user_country and user_language.

How to make it save the other elements on the list?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are continuously updating the same object.

You just need to create the `UserCountry` and `UserLanguage` inside the loop. As of now you are creating outside the loop. Just move them inside the loops.

For ex :

```
for (String s : user_country) {
        UserCountry userCountry = new UserCountry();
        userCountry.setUserId(intIdUser);
        userCountry.setCountryId(Integer.parseInt(s));

        session.getTransaction().begin();
        session.persist(userCountry);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Comment: This one helped! Thanks.

Comment: @SURESH ATA: Can you please provide a solution to a DELETE row solution using JPA?

Comment: it's weired, in his question, he said `loops are saving just first element on the list user_country and user_language`. but it should be last one if he repeats updating the same persisitent instance, isn't it?

Comment: @ROROROOROROR Since all are same. he confused :)

Comment: Yup :)
Any solution os deleting rows?

Comment: The same way you saved them ..No ?